# Android DJI UX SDK - problem reading location - battery drain

Tags: android, background, battery, dji-sdk

I tried to run a sample DJI UX SDK app that DJI provides on their github repo:
https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-Android/tree/master/sample

However, when I open the app, the dji sdk registration starts and ends, but the GPS location pin in the status bar appears and doesn't disappear.

[image]

**The GPS pin is also present when I put the app to the background.** This results in the system telling me after some time that the application is draining too much battery.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: have you give permission for this app to access phone location?

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai yes